# Decodificar con Hex Decode desde mi host, cómo lo hago?

Tags: javascript, php

tengo un texto codificado que se ve como esto `\x3C\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x20\x77\x69\`.

He visto una página en internet que lo decodifica, ddecode.com/hexdecoder/ pero me gustaría decodificarlo desde mi host, me pregunto cómo lo hace?

Pienso que quizás sea un script en javascript o tal vez en php, alguno tiene alguna idea?

Answer (score 2):

Es importante saber que `\x` nos indica que es un [caracter hexadecimal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_hexadecimal).
El rango máximo alcanzado es `\xFF` que es `255` y responde a caracteres [ASCII](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

#### Solución PHP

Podemos utilizar [iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.iconv.php):

> Convierte un string a la codificación de caracteres indicada

Ejemplo:

```
echo iconv('ASCII', 'UTF-8', "\x3C\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x20\x77\x69");
// Salida "<iframe wi"
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9690e62b885544459772f4c4eac6813e5fbc2b6d)</kbd>

---

Otra opción es convertir individualmente cada caracter `ASCII` a su equivalente usando:

- [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace-callback): Realiza una búsqueda y sustitución de una expresión regular usando una llamada de retorno
- [hexdec](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.hexdec.php): Hexadecimal a decimal
- [chr](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.chr): Devuelve una cadena de un caracter que contiene el carácter especificado por ascii

Ejemplo:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('#\\\\x([0-9a-f]{2})#im', function($matches){
    return chr(hexdec($matches[1]));
}, "\x3C\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x20\x77\x69");
// Salida "<iframe wi"
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c3c53f8b8cefd3a5284470be2751035236dc8006)</kbd>

Comment: Genial, gracias por responder Marcos! Estoy recuperando el código encriptado de una página web con `file_get_contents` y luego con `preg_match_all` para identificarlo, entonces pongo el código dentro de una variable pero al intentar usar `echo iconv('ASCII', 'UTF-8', "$decode");` la salida sigue siendo encriptada, es normal?

Comment: @Daniel, me es difícil entender cual es el problema sin ver exactamente lo que sucede. ¿Podrás pasarme un link para ver lo que me comentas?

Comment: puedes fijarte en este link https://paiza.io/projects/-Bu_izq9vf-90Cd116olkA

Comment: @Daniel, actualice mi respuesta para darte una segunda opción la cual verifique que funciona en tu [link](https://paiza.io/projects/VG1jQ6HCa9jd75u91-qM_g).